# Python - open a command which open another shell

Tags: python

I am writing a Python code which calls a command line (e.g. python itself) and the command will open its own shell. How can Python take control of this shell?

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['./testprg'])

# testprg will open its own shell 
# so the code below will not work
subprocess.call(['i 2'])
```

testprg is another program which open a shell prompt. Enter "i 2" will trigger a "insert" command with the value 2.

Answer (score 2):

It can't. `subprocess` does not interact with interactive shells.

You need to use `stdin=PIPE` in the first subprocess an write `'i 2\n'` to that pipe.

Consider using [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) though if you want to interact with interactive programs. It might make your life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`subprocess.Popen.communicate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate). If it's just about receiving some lines and sending commands to the other process, it should be what you're looking for.

Some example:

```
pout, perr = Popen([tools['PASSWD'], username], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,
        stderr=PIPE).communicate("%s\n%s\n" % (password, password))
```

Comment: I have amended my code and there is an error. %1 is not a valid win32 application. I am running a Linux command instead.

Comment: Don't talk in riddles. Tell us your exact command, that you used, and copy the error as it is. My example is also from Linux.

Comment: Pout,perr = Popen(['./cmdl'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate('i 2\n')   Is this correct? Sorry I am quite new in python.

Comment: This will start `./cmd` and type in `i 2`, and return, as if you would type in from keyboard. So then you get the error? You're running linux and it tells you something about win32?